# CSS Stretching sidebar to 100% of page. Breaks when window resized or content too large

Tags: html, css, height, stretch

Been struggling with this for at least a couple hours now. Tried searching around but no solution seems to be working. So anyways, I have a template that I'm working on, and the issue that I'm having is that the sidebar on the left just will not stretch all the way down! If the window is maximized, it looks totally fine. Once you resize the window though it breaks, leaving a large gap between the sidebar and the footer. It also breaks if the content goes down the page any more than it currently does...

See for yourself here: http://bakedcraft.ca/laboratory/testsites/crock/template.html

and the css: http://bakedcraft.ca/laboratory/testsites/crock/css/default.css

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to your .main class

right now your side bar is 100% height of the window, not the main container.  by adding position:relative to the sidebar's parent, when the sidebar is 100% height, it becomes 100% of the main div.

Comment: that's strange that it didn't work for you.  when i add position: relative; to default.css line in the div.main element on line 86 (using Chrome developer tools), it seems to work fine.  If you want a javascript approach, yo can try $(".sidebar").height($(".main").height());  this will set the height of the sidebar to the height of the main div

Comment: interesting. I just tried the same thing, and your right, it does work! In between making this post and your original comment though I changed up the css a bunch due to a couple pretty bad bugs I discovered when taking away the content, so when I tried making it positon: relative on my local copy it didnt work. I think I can figure it out now though, thanks!

Comment: glad to help.  if you don't mind, can you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this isn't really an answer but it's not letting me write a comment...

I looked at your code in firebug (firefox + web developer add-on) and it's showing a box constraint of **467px height** I tried to quickly find where this 467px are coming from but can't see it with quick look (it's 4 AM).  It's inheriting that height from somewhere, most likely from a combination of other size constraints of related elements.  With all the positioning you have going on, in may be hard to locate.

One suggestion I have is if you plan on making a fluid layout you should work with em's rather than straight pixels.  As I said, this isn't an answer but I did notice the size constraint of your sidebar.  If this problem is still open in the morning I'll see if I can get a better look at it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I was running your problem through my head and I think I figured it out. Forgive me cuz I'm typing this on my phone and can't use firebug to verify if I'm right or not but the constraint I noticed earlier of 467px is n't inherited from another container it's being constained by the text in the sidebar div. If u were to add more text the box will grow with it. I believe what u may want to do is make a child conatiner within the side bar div. Your main sidebar div will only house your grey background color grey. Create a child div within the sidebar div and put your text and images into those. Make sure on the parent div you make it's height 100%. The height of the elements inside the child div shouldn't need height specifications since they will be inherited from the parent sidebar div. Hope this makes sense.

You can do the fix mentioned earlier with using jquery but remember if someone shuts of their JavaScript then your issue remains and your page will break. You should try to find and fix the root cause not use a bandaid that can be taken off.